# Changing default product view per page in backend

Tags: product, admin, backend

By default, in catalog - > manage product, magento shows 20 products, is it possibile to set the default number to, 50, 100 or 200 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your `/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php`

Search the file for a line of code that reads:

```
parent::__construct();
```

Once you find it, paste the below code on the line beneath it:

```
$this->setDefaultLimit(100);
```

**PS :** 
Do not edit the core files, you should overwrite it

Comment: This does not work in Create New order -> Please Select Products to Add. Any idea why? Cleared cache already..

Answer (score 0):

try to Edit the grid.phtml file located:

.../app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

At line 81-87:

```
<select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>” onchange="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>JsObject.loadByElement(this)"> 
  <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option> 
  <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option> 
  <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option> 
  <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option> 
  <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option> 
</select>
```

Changing the above to the below for example:

```
<select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>” onchange="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>JsObject.loadByElement(this)"> 
  <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option> 
  <option value="300"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==300): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>300</option> 
  <option value="500"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==500): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>500</option> 
  <option value="1000"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==1000): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>1000</option> 
  <option value="2000"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==2000): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>2000</option> 
</select>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks